# Sending bytes to Server and then reading it back in from Client

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, outputstream, secret-key

I'm creating a small encryption program in Java and I want to send a byte [] from a server to a client so that it can be read in for decrypt purposes on the client side.

Server (generates the encrypted key - encrypted with somePublicKey)

```
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, somePublicKey);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = c.doFinal(generatedKey.getEncoded());
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(encryptedBytes);
    out.close();
```

Client (reads in bytes[] so that decryption can take place)

```
    ObjectInputStream inside = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    byte[] bytesToDecrypt = (byte[])inside.readObject();

    cd.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cd.doFinal(bytesToDecrypt);
    SecretKey decrypted = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.length, "AES");
```

When I try to read in the bytes on the Client side, I get javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try flushing: `out.writeObject(encryptedBytes); out.flush();`

Comment: hi @flkes - just did that - still giving me the same error.

Comment: When you made `generatedKey` did you use `KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();` to match the decoding format ?

Comment: Show how you initialized all of the objects here, `c`, `cd`, keys, etc

Comment: @flkes Sorted it out. I wasn't sending it in the right order. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem! You should post and accept your own answer to help others down the road